# Change border brush from skyblue in wizard control of extended wpf toolkit

Tags: wpf, xaml, border, wpftoolkit, wizard

I'm using Wizard control of Extended wpf toolkit package.

I would like to change color of the border. See sky blue in image below:

[image]

I tried set broder brush\background to wizard\wizard page\window controls, but it failed.

Anybody know how to change it?

Your assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code, where you think the problem is, and refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Kory Gill The code isn't relevant here.. I try all properties which sounds me relevant and it failed

Comment: In general, I have seen the SO community willing to help people who show effort, research, and identify what's blocking them, etc.  The way I read this question, I do not see a lot of that. You will get more out of your question if you put the image in your post instead of some hyperlink that people will be hesitant to click on, if you have working code that is Green and you want to change it to Blue for example...people can help more easily. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: thanks, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have provided more info, I can see that your question title does not match what you asking to change.  You are not asking to change the color of the border of the Wizard Control, you are asking to change the color of the WPF Window.

It takes some time to get things right, and I highly discourage doing this if you app will be used by people with disabilities, who need high contrast, who customized their desktop to a certain color because of color blindness, and the list goes on...Microsoft has worked very hard to address such issues with the defaults.

BUT...you can change this by restyling your Window Style.  You can find plenty of code examples.

Here are two:

[Can i set the window border color in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170620/can-i-set-the-window-border-color-in-wpf)

[How can I style the border and title bar of a window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978444/how-can-i-style-the-border-and-title-bar-of-a-window-in-wpf)